# How to zoom, pan, center and scale to fit on node click both for the clicked node and all its connected nodes/edges?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to build a network graph similar to [this one](http://www.wineandcheesemap.com/) however I couldn't google myself to an example/tutorial/hints explaining how to include the connected nodes when doing the zoom, pan, center, scale to fit.

Is there an example of something similar, built with d3 (ideally also react, but not a must, but just what I'm going to use to build my implementation)

I couldn't join the d3 discord to ask, so I hope it's fine to ask this in here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the easiest way to zoom into a specified rectangle in an SVG is to set the [`viewBox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) of the SVG. The code snippet below uses [Observable](https://observablehq.com/) to generate a random graph and fit it nicely into a rectangle. Note that three nodes highlighted in red form a triangle. You can use the "Zoom in" button to zoom into to a box that contains that triangle. The implementation is in [this Observable notebook](https://observablehq.com/d/7133cc55cc1b5f01) and the critical piece of code looks something like so:

```
d3.select(zoom_button).on("input", function () {
  let xs = [];
  let ys = [];
  d3.select(anim)
    .selectAll("circle.zoom")
    .each(function (c) {
      xs.push(c.x);
      ys.push(c.y);
    });
  let [xmin, xmax] = d3.extent(xs).map(anim.x_scale);
  let [ymax, ymin] = d3.extent(ys).map(anim.y_scale);
  let W = xmax - xmin;
  let H = ymax - ymin;
  let viewBox;
  if (zoom_button.value % 2 == 1) {
    viewBox = [xmin - pad, ymin - pad, W + 2 * pad, H + 2 * pad];
    d3.select(zoom_button).select("button").text("Zoom out");
  } else {
    viewBox = [0, 0, w, h];
    d3.select(zoom_button).select("button").text("Zoom in");
  }
  d3.select(anim).transition().duration(500).attr("viewBox", viewBox);
});
```

```html
<div>
<div style="margin: 5px;" id="observablehq-viewof-redo-f7b693ca"></div>
<div style="margin: 5px;" id="observablehq-zoom_button-f7b693ca"></div>
</div>
<div id="observablehq-anim-f7b693ca"></div>


<script type="module">
import {Runtime, Inspector} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@observablehq/runtime@5/dist/runtime.js";
import define from "https://api.observablehq.com/d/7133cc55cc1b5f01.js?v=3";
new Runtime().module(define, name => {
  if (name === "viewof redo") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-viewof-redo-f7b693ca"));
  if (name === "zoom_button") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-zoom_button-f7b693ca"));
  if (name === "anim") return new Inspector(document.querySelector("#observablehq-anim-f7b693ca"));
});
</script>
```