# How do I fix zoom on selection for d3 force directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to get the window to reposition and zoom on a selected node in a d3 force directed graph. Ideally, it will be slightly off centre to accommodate a modal window to the left.

I've tried modifying the translate properties for when a node is clicked, and trying to adjust how nodes are ticked, but to no avail. I can't seem to get it to zoom on the node. It either zooms to the top left corner of the network (0,0 origin) or in the centre of the screen.

I was originally able to get it to work in a simplified version (Example 1: https://codepen.io/sgarnea/pen/BaGXqgb) but when I introduced a hover feature for showing node connections, it seems to have broken the zoom functionality (Example 2: https://codepen.io/sgarnea/pen/jOQgeRN?editors=0010).

I'd like Example 2 to work with the zoom functionality of the first.

It seems to be zooming to the centre of the window and not repositioning if another node is selected when there is a zoom focus already active (selecting another node when zoomed does not move the zoom).

*Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

Example 2 code relevant to issue:

**Zoom functionality**

```
var node = g.append("g")

.attr("class", "nodes")
   .selectAll("g")
   .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("id", d => d)

node.append("circle")
   .attr("r", R)
   .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group);})  

   .on("click", clicked); //clicked function below
```

---

```
//general zoom call  
 var zoom = d3.zoom()
   .scaleExtent([0.4, 2]) // 40% zoom in and 200% zoom in
   .on("zoom", zoomed);
```

---

```
//zoom and pan  
 var svg = d3.select("svg") 
   .attr("width", "100%")
   .attr("height", "100%")
   .call(d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.4,2]).on("zoom", function () {
 svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}))
   .append("g") //appends group to background
   .on("click", stopped, true)

var rect = d3.select("rect")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .on("click", reset); //clicking the rect resets zoom

const g = svg.append("g");
```

---

```
//zoom on click, zoom and scale position and ability to move zoom if selecting another node
 function clicked(d){
 if (active.node() === this) return reset();
 active.classed("active", false);

 active = d3.select(this)
   .classed("active", true);  

 svg.transition() //transition for the zoom on successful click (active)
   .duration(900) //how long the transition takes
   .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
   .translate(width / 2, height / 2) //centre of the zoom area
   .scale(2) //scale for the zoom based on svg size
   .translate(-(+active.attr("cx")), -(+active.attr("cy"))) //focuses zoom on active node

   }

function reset() {
   active.classed("active", false);
   active = d3.select(null);

   svg.transition()
     .duration(900)
     .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
     .scale(0.8)
     );
    }

  function zoomed() {   //zoom event handler function
     g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
 }

function stopped() {
     if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) d3.event.stopPropagation();
    }`
```

**Ticking node and link position (likely the issue)**

```
function ticked() {
link
     .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
     .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
     .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
     .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

node //different from Example 1 to allow hover feature to function
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674483/how-to-zoom-pan-center-and-scale-to-fit-on-node-click-both-for-the-clicked-nod/74682617#74682617) will help.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you!